# Javascript: attempting to fill an array with a prompt but prompt is not displaying

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to call a method that asks the user how many entries they would like to make into an array and then prompts the user for each entry. I know this is likely a simple error but I cannot tell why my prompt is not working.

```
 <script>
function testScore(){
    var numberofScores = prompt("enter the number of scores:","");
    var scores = new Array();
    var whichScore=1;
    for(var i=0; i<numberofScores; i++; whichScore++){

    score[i]=prompt("enter score "+whichScore+":");
}
}
</script>

<a href="" onclick="testScore()">
Start Test score script
</a><br>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Looks like you need to refresh your knowledge of how [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) works...

Comment: 1. you need a comma between `i++` and `whichScore++` - 2. you declare `scores`, then attempt to set `score`.

Comment: you also need to parseInt the response you get from prompt()

Comment: @Cruiser you don't in this case, but one should in general.

Comment: he's getting it as a string, so if the user enters 13, numberofScores will not iterate 13 times

Comment: @Cruiser You sure? https://jsfiddle.net/ye4z1ktz/

Comment: I stand corrected. i suppose the < operator casts the string as an int, if it can

Comment: @Cruiser It does indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loop is configured with 3 sections and thus two semi-colons. You had `whichScore++` in a 4th section after adding a third semi-colon. You could have added it to the end of the configuration with a comma. But, adding it to the loop body, and not part of the loop declaration is cleaner. That said, the variable is not even needed. Just use `(i + 1)` and note that we're not modifying `i` here, we're just using an offset of it for display purposes only.

Also, in the loop: `score[i]`, needs to be `scores[i]` and your `<a>` element should have an `href="#"` instead of an empty attribute.

Lastly, don't use inline HTML event handling attributes as they:

- Make the code more difficult to read and lead to code duplication.
- Cause global wrapper functions to be created around your supplied
  attribute value that alter the binding of `this` in your function.
- Don't follow the **[W3C DOM Event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)** standard.

Use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** in JavaScript instead:

```js
// When the DOM content is ready
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get a reference to the hyperlink and create a click event handler for it:
  document.getElementById("makeScores").addEventListener("click", testScore);

  function testScore(){
    var numberofScores = prompt("enter the number of scores:","");
    var scores = new Array();
  
    for(var i = 0; i < numberofScores; i++){
      scores[i] = prompt("enter score " + (i + 1) + ":");
    }
  
    console.log(scores);
  }

});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="makeScores">Start Test score script</a>
```

Comment: whichScore++ can still e a part of loop declaration. Infact you can eliminate it and use variable `i` only

Comment: Thank you! this has resolved my initial prompt issue however now I do not get a prompt for each score after as defined here  score[i] = prompt("enter score " + whichScore + ":");

Comment: @user3216792 See my code sample which does work and read my post. The code is not `score[i]`, it's `scores[i]`. Also, work with your developer tools open and the console showing (F12). This will show you what errors you have in your code and where.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function testScore(){
    var numberofScores = prompt("enter the number of scores:","");
    var scores = new Array();
    var whichScore=1;
    for(var i=0; i<numberofScores; i++, whichScore++){
     scores.push(prompt("enter score "+whichScore+":"));
     //or 
     //scores[i]= (prompt("enter score "+whichScore+":"));
    }
}
</script>

<a href="" onclick="testScore()">
Start Test score script
</a><br>
```

1. your variable is scores
2. Use Array.push, since you did not declare the array length in array constructor. Edit : You can also use scores[i]. It will work as well.

Comment: `array.push()` is one way to add items to an array, but if you assign a value to an index that hasn't been used in the array yet, that index will be created.

Comment: Yes realized it later. Editing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSFiddle using your code. You have a lot going on here

https://jsfiddle.net/tcoedqkf/

First off, your for loop needs to have a comma besides the increments (although for readability I would do it in the for loop)

```
for(var i=0; i<numberofScores; i++,whichScore++){
```

Your variable name in the for loop is incorrect (missing an S)

```
scores[i]=prompt("enter score "+whichScore+":");
```

Comment: Looks like someone took self-promotion to mean demotion of others :P

Comment: I read that 10 times and I don't see what you mean. If you can point out what I wrote to demote someone then I would gladly edit it! I'm definitely not trying to put down anyone. Just trying to help out :)

In my defense, the question was to point out his errors of which I did well I think :P

Comment: No, It wasn't targeted to you. It was to the person who downvoted w/o commenting why he did so.

Comment: ahhhh I follow!

Answer (score 0):

`for` only have three sections (separated by a semicolon `;`): initialization, the condition and the incrementation. If you want to initialize or increment more variables use a comma `,`. Like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberofScores; i++, whichScore++) {
    // ...
```

Since `whichScore` is basically just `i + 1` you won't need to have two variables for that, just `i` will do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberofScores; i++) {
    score[i] = prompt("enter score " + (i + 1) + ":");
// ...
```

**Note** that the parenthesis in `(i + 1)` are necessary so the numbers are added instead of concatenated.